# Firestore doesn't work in Xcode Simulator after the last update

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I'm developing an app with SwiftUI using Firebase Auth, Firestore and Firebase Storage. I uploaded my app in TestFlight and it still workes on my device perfectly. But even though I didn't change a single code, after I update my Xcode and Simulator to newest version (Version 15.1) my codes for reading and writing new data to Firestore stopped working. It still saves new user to firebase Auth but don't update the database. Is there anyone who is deaing with the same issue?

(I update the packages to newest version but it didn't help)

Comment: Hello:) can you try to clean your build folder; this should fix the issue. To clean it go to Product and click Clean Build Folder in Xcode. I hope this helps and please let me know if it is not solved.

Comment: Heyy, unfortunately it didn't work. I'm getting "Stream error: 'Unavailable: failed to connect to all addresses; last error: UNKNOWN: No route to host'" error.

Comment: It can be caused if you have a weak network, or if your using a server that is down

Comment: I checked, and I don't. Dunno what to do :D It's also really absurd that Firebase Authentication works but Firestore doesn't even though I didn't touch a single code.